# How do I find all the functional indexes on a column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, indexing

Say I have a program that searches a database for columns to modify, as part of a database conversion process.

If I attempt to alter a column with a functional index defined gives the following error:

```
ORA-30556: functional index is defined on the column to be modified
```

[Looking up the ORA code](http://ora-30556.ora-code.com/), the solution is to "Drop the functional index before attempting to modify the column."

Great!  So how do I find all the functional indexes on that column?

The `user_ind_columns` view looks like a good start, but functional indexes have things like "SYS_NC00042$" in their `COLUMN` column.  Looking around the other `user_` views, I'm not seeing anything obvious.  Am I missing something?

Or am I going about this the wrong way entirely?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The table `user_ind_expressions` describes expressions of function based indexes.

[Oracle 11.2 link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_5308.htm)

Comment: I was hoping for just the column name, but I suppose using `like '%COLUMN_NAME%' has a resonably low probability of false positives (which aren't much of a tragedy anyway).

Comment: I don't know of a better way.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the `INDEX_TYPE` column of `USER_INDEXES`:

```
select table_name, index_name, index_type
from user_indexes
where index_type like 'FUNCTION%'
order by table_name, index_name

TABLE_NAME                      INDEX_NAME                      INDEX_TYPE                 
------------------------------  ------------------------------  ---------------------------
SOME_TABLE                      SOME_TABLE_FUNC_INDEX           FUNCTION-BASED NORMAL
```

Comment: That shows you any functional indexes on the table, but it doesn't help identify which indexes, if any, reference a particular column.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901610/13622340),
You can use the `FUNCIDX_STATUS` in `ALL_INDEXES` table which will tell you whether the index is functional based or not `NULL`, whether functional based index is enabled `ENABLED` or functional based index is `DISABLED`.

```
SELECT table_name, index_name FROM ALL_INDEXES WHERE FUNCIDX_STATUS != NULL ORDER BY table_name, index_name
```